# Angular js and spring mvc

Tags: angularjs, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
var Buyers = [  
               {
                  "first_name" : "Raj",                 
                  "last_name" : "Pilla"

               },
               {
                  "first_name" : "Ajit",                    
                  "last_name" : "Bambaras"

               }
             ]; 
var Seller = {
                  "first_name" : "Simon",                   
                  "last_name" : "Mathew"
              };
```

How we can post this data to controller using angular js post method also what we need to write in java controller..?

Comment: multiple object in the sence ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, if you are trying to post multiple objects of the same type. You just need to use a list.**

For e.g., in your case it will be :

```
    public @ResponseBody String PostService(@RequestBody List<Seller> seller) {

    }
```

**However, if you're trying to send multiple objects of different types, you should instead use List to capture all the objects and then cast them as required.**

For e.g.

```
    public @ResponseBody String PostService(@RequestBody List<Object> requestObjects) {
        Seller seller = (Seller) requestObjects.get(0);
        Buyer buyer = (Buyer) requestObjects.get(1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. How we should call this in angularjs controller?